# Null pointer exception error recycle view in android?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

So im getting this error java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure
In my main activity after setting the adapter.

Im not sure what it is im doing wrong. I have tried to read other issues on this but the solution to it is not working. Would appreciate it if some one could guide me in the right direction as im new to programming in android. Thanks.

Also here is the full error

```
log:06-26 12:41:50.014  31158-31158/alexgwartney.treehouseblogreader E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: alexgwartney.treehouseblogreader, PID: 31158
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:1764)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16849)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:824)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:500)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16849)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5378)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16849)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5378)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:444)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16849)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5378)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16849)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5378)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1621)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:742)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:607)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16849)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5378)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2368)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16849)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2271)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1334)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1532)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1211)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6282)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5323)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
public String url = "http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/api/get_recent_summary/?count=20";
public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;

content[] mDataset;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

    if(isNetworkAvailable()) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                try {
                    String jsonData = response.body().string();
                    Log.v(TAG, jsonData);
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        getCurrentDetails(jsonData);
                        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(mDataset);
                        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

                        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
                        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

                        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught: ", e);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught: ", e);
                }
            }
        });
    }


}


private content[] getCurrentDetails(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(jsonData);

    JSONArray data = forecast.getJSONArray("posts");

     mDataset = new content[data.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject jsonDay = data.getJSONObject(i);
        content day = new content();

        day.setId(jsonDay.getInt("id"));
        day.setUrl(jsonDay.getString("url"));
        day.setTitle(jsonDay.getString("title"));
        day.setDate(jsonDay.getString("date"));
        day.setAuthor(jsonDay.getString("author"));
        day.setThumbnail(jsonDay.getString("thumbnail"));
        mDataset[i] = day;
    }


    return mDataset;

}


// This will check if there is a net work conection
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isAvailable = false;
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        isAvailable = true;
    }
    return isAvailable;
}
```

}

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.HourViewHolder> {
public  content[] mDataset;


public MyAdapter(content[] data) {
    mDataset = data;

}




//  the lay out is not the correct lay out but its just there for a example.
@Override
public HourViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.test, parent, false);
    HourViewHolder viewHolder = new HourViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(HourViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bindHour(mDataset[position]);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.length;
}

public class HourViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView mId;
    public TextView mUrl;
    public TextView mTitle;
    public TextView mDate;
    public TextView mAuthor;
    public TextView mThumbnail;

    public HourViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.blogid);
        mUrl= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.url);
        mTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        mDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        mAuthor = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.author);
        mThumbnail= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    }

    public void bindHour(content hour) {
        mId.setText(hour.getId());
        mUrl.setText(hour.getUrl());
        mTitle.setText(hour.getTitle());
        mDate.setText(hour.getDate());
        mAuthor.setText(hour.getAuthor());
        mThumbnail.setText(hour.getThumbnail());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Also if  you want me to post the adapter code let me know thank you.

Comment: For which line are you getting the null pointer exception..Also post the error logs

Comment: Try this --`LinearLayoutManager lm = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
lm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(lm);`

Comment: nope giving me the same error?

Comment: does the error have any thing to do with my xml file?

Comment: or is it only dealing with the adapter?

Comment: Can you post the adapter source code?

Comment: This is tough since the stacktrace only refers to classes and methods from the Android API. I suggest that you start a new project from scratch and gradually add features similar to your app until you can figure out how to recreate the NPE.

Comment: thats the problem i did that with this form a nother project that was implementing a list view but it was doing it through intents since it was on another page.

Comment: mId.setText(hour.getId()) would throw an error since its int. But I'm not sure that is causing the exception. You should use mId.setText(String.valueOf(hour.getId())). Also make sure that the layout manager is set prior to setting adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Set the layoutManager before setting the adapter. Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

You should init the recyclerview in your oncreate and not in your callback.

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //init recyclerview
            mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            mAdapter = new MyAdapter(new MyAdatpter());
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(url)
                        .build();

                Call call = client.newCall(request);
                call.enqueue(new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                        try {
                            String jsonData = response.body().string();
                            Log.v(TAG, jsonData);
                            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
// only switch the recyclerview adapter
// or extend your adapter with a clear() and add(List<>) function to avoid creating always a new adapter
// This code must run on ui thread
                                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getCurrentDetails(jsonData)));
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught: ", e);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught: ", e);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Added comments.

Comment: Which parts are you suggesting the OP change? How will they solve his problem?

Answer (score 0):

So i figured it out turns out i needed to run the adapter on the main ui thread.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public String url = "http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/api/get_recent_summary/?count=20";
    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;

    content[] mDataset;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


        if(isNetworkAvailable()) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .build();

            Call call = client.newCall(request);
            call.enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                    try {
                        String jsonData = response.body().string();
                        Log.v(TAG, jsonData);
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            getCurrentDetails(jsonData);

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(mDataset);
                                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                                }
                            });



                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught: ", e);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught: ", e);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private content[] getCurrentDetails(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        JSONArray data = forecast.getJSONArray("posts");
        mDataset = new content[data.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jsonDay = data.getJSONObject(i);
            content day = new content();

            day.setId(jsonDay.getInt("id"));
            day.setUrl(jsonDay.getString("url"));
            day.setTitle(jsonDay.getString("title"));
            day.setDate(jsonDay.getString("date"));
            day.setAuthor(jsonDay.getString("author"));
            day.setThumbnail(jsonDay.getString("thumbnail"));
            mDataset[i] = day;
        }
        return mDataset;
    }

    // This will check if there is a net work conection
    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)
                getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isAvailable = false;
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            isAvailable = true;
        }
        return isAvailable;
    }
}
```